# php-src - ZEND_TSRMLS_CACHE_UPDATE - what is it and when it is needed?

Tags: php, c++, c, windows, thread-safety

What does the `ZEND_TSRMLS_CACHE_UPDATE` directive in `php/ext` [skeleton file](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/92ac598aabd336593a47ed3959f1031674b763e6/ext/skeleton/skeleton.c#L52) do?

When and why is it needed?

When another init. function like `PHP_MINIT_FUNCTION(%EXTNAME%)` is added, is the `ZEND_TSRMLS_CACHE_UPDATE` directive needed there as the first statement in that function too?

Comment: Have you looked at [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-tlsgetvalue) description? The macro `ZEND_TSRMLS_CACHE_UPDATE` expands to the WINAPI function `TlsGetValue()`. There is also a [description and example](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-at/windows/win32/procthread/using-thread-local-storage) of the usage.

Comment: Supplement: The question is related to Windows, but on POSIX systems the macro expands to the POSIX-Threads function `pthread_getspecific()`. If it's clearer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First thing First that is your question is not clear as of two reasons:

1. You have to mention that you are trying to understand ZTS i.e Zend
   Thread Safe with PHP
2. That you file compiling or understanding what are your system
   requirements i.e what OS you are using and which thread type you are using.

Second thing you have not understand the difference between MINIT and RINIT first let us understand the difference between the two

## MINIT Vs RINIT

You must understand the global variables in C programming. Assuming that you know have some knowledge about extension compiling of PHP. In PHP the globals ares divided into two types:

#### 1. True Globals / MINI

True Globals are traditional C global variables as they are not bad in design but cannot be protected in Threads concurrency running environment. PHP allows them to read when PHP treading a request. True Global variables can be changed inside or outside Threads environment. Lets see the example to explain it further:

```
static int variable; /* true global */

PHP_MINIT(my_ext) /* PHP Module initialization */
{
        if (something()) {
                variable = 3; /* writing to a true global */
        }
}
```

Above code explains about every PHP extension look like. So called MINIT hooks is about PHP extension initialization. During such step, PHP is starting and one can then write or read to global variables safely, like this done in example.

#### 2. Thread Globals / RINI

As Threads are created to handle several request at same time and it is very important to keep the each variable value intact within that thread, so that values are read or written by that thread only. So, initialization of Threads requests are done through RINIT. Now the same example will be like this:

```
PHP_RINIT(my_ext) /* PHP Request initialization */
{
        if (something()) {
                MYEXT_G(variable) = 3; /* writing to a thread global */
        }
}
```

There is only 1 difference i.e. using MYEXT_G macro that I will explain later in this answer.

To understand thing better you might also need to understand TSRM

## TSRM

For ZTS is designed for using Thread Safe Resource Manager layer what we call the TSRM layer. This is just some plain C code, for threads nothing more but some explanation as required to understand things. It enables some low-level threading libraries :

1. Gnu Portable Thread,
2. Posix Threads,
3. State Threads,
4. Win32 Threads or
5. BeThreads.

### TSRM Boot

AT TSRM boot PHP calls `tsrm_startup()`. As PHP starting doesn't how may threads or resources required to build safe protection. It will prepare a single table having checkup for each thread created. This startup step is also important as it is here that we create both the TLS key, and the TLS mutex we'll need to synchronize.

```
static pthread_key_t tls_key;

TSRM_API int tsrm_startup(int expected_threads, 
                          int expected_resources, int debug_level, char *debug_filename)
{
        pthread_key_create( &tls_key, 0 ); /* Create the key */
        ....
        ....
}

#define MUTEX_T pthread_mutex_t *

TSRM_API MUTEX_T tsrm_mutex_alloc(void)
{
        MUTEX_T mutexp;
        mutexp = (pthread_mutex_t *)malloc(sizeof(pthread_mutex_t));
        pthread_mutex_init(mutexp,NULL);
        return mutexp;
}
```

### TSRM Resources

Time to add new resources threads. Memory area has a size, and would need some initialization (constructor) and deinitialization (destructor). That memory area, which is called a TSRM resource, will be given a unique resource ID by the TSRM layer. Caller should save ID, as it will need to be given back the protected memory area from TSRM to read or write variable values.

```
TSRM_API ts_rsrc_id ts_allocate_id(ts_rsrc_id *rsrc_id, 
        size_t size, ts_allocate_ctor ctor, ts_allocate_dtor dtor)
{
     ....
     //For allocation of memory saving constructor and destruction function 
     // Saving Size of required memory allocated
     // Resources ID Returning back
}
```

### On request startup

At the very beginning of every new request, the ts_resource_ex() function is called. This function reads the current thread id and tries to fetch the ressources allocated for this thread, aka the memory areas dedicated for globals for the current thread.

## ZEND_TSRMLS_CACHE_UPDATE

Now your answer to question about ZEND_TSRMLS_CACHE_UPDATE.

```
/* {{{ PHP_RINIT_FUNCTION
 */
PHP_RINIT_FUNCTION(%EXTNAME%)
{
#if defined(ZTS) && defined(COMPILE_DL_%EXTNAMECAPS%)
    ZEND_TSRMLS_CACHE_UPDATE();
#endif

    return SUCCESS;
}
/* }}} */
```

Here is the macro expansion :

```
#define ZEND_TSRMLS_CACHE_UPDATE() _tsrm_ls_cache = tsrm_get_ls_cache();
```

And for pthread implementation :

```
#define tsrm_get_ls_cache pthread_getspecific(tls_key)
```

Finally you should better understand how globals are now accessed in extensions, using macros :

```
#ifdef ZTS
#define MYEXT_G(v) (((MYEXT_globals *) (*((void ***) _tsrm_ls_cache))[((MYEXT_globals_id)-1)])->(v))
```

using the MYEXT_G() macro to access globals, when using a thread environment, it will expand to probe the `_tsrm_ls_cache` area using the id of this extension : `MYEXT_globals_id`.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. So if I do not to set any per module global variable, it is safe to omit the `ZEND_TSRMLS_CACHE_UPDATE` call? What is performance impact of `pthread_getspecific` or the equivalent on Windows? Is there any reason why the `ZEND_TSRMLS_CACHE_UPDATE` directive is not inlined the the `PHP_RINIT_FUNCTION(%EXTNAME%)` macro or similar code when the PHP does the request init?

Comment: It depends on your implementation. I have given you the idea about things how are done. don't know which implementation you are compiling or reading. My personal point of view is not to drop things until you are 100% sure about the impact.